# How to populate a dictionary from a file while disregarding the header?

Tags: python

I have this function that's populating itself from another file. I'm having difficulty with avoiding the header of the txt file which begins with ;;; and that the first aspect of the dictionary is supposed to be the words which are in uppercase and the stuff that follows it are the phonemes. I'm not sure which part of my code is wrong :S

```
def read_file(file):
    """ (file open for reading) -> pronunciation dictionary

    Read file, which is in the format of the CMU Pronouncing
    Dictionary, and return the pronunciation dictionary.
    """
    line = file.readline()
    while line != ';;;':
        line = file.readline()
    pronun_dict = {}
    line = file.readline()
    while line != '':
        word = line.isupper()
        phoneme = line.strip()
        if phoneme not in pronun_dict:
            pronun_dict[phoneme] = [word]
        line = file.readline()
    return pronun_dict
```

http://gyazo.com/31b414c39cc907bc917f7a1129f4019d
the above link is a screenshot of what the text file looks like!

Comment: There is a dictreader class in python. Did you try to use is?

Comment: Can you please show a sample of the text file?

Comment: @thefourtheye :) I posted a snap of what the textfile looks like!

Answer (score 0):

`while line != ';;;':` will only be met when the header does not exactly match ';;;'. I assume the header can contain much more data. Try, instead, `while line.startswith(';;;'):`. As long as this condition is met, the next line in the file will be assigned to variable `line`. Therefore, your code will loop through that block until a line that doesn't begin with `;;;` is found.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_startswith.htm